# Convert CryptAcquireContext VB6 code to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, cryptography, vb6-migration

I have a very old VB6 code that is used to generate the hash for the password. The code uses `CryptAcquireContext` function along with advapi32.dll to generate the Hash. There is so much code with variables having hex values etc. The code will take forever to migrate to ASP.NET.

We have lots of data encrypted using this Hash code and we don't have a way to decrypt it back to plain text.

I need to write similar code in ASP.NET C# that generates the same hash as the VB6 code does.

Example: Look at the picture below on how it generates HASH from plaintext:

[image]

**Working C# Code in Windows forms only with exception that CryptAcquireContext returns false when the program is run second time:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CryptoGraphicHash
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static uint CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = 0x8;

        static uint CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET = 0x20;

        static uint ALG_CLASS_HASH = 32768;
        // Algorithm types
        static uint ALG_TYPE_ANY = 0;

        static uint PROV_RSA_FULL = 1;
        static uint ALG_SID_SHA = 4;

        static string MS_DEF_PROV = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
        static uint CALG_SHA = ALG_CLASS_HASH + ALG_TYPE_ANY + ALG_SID_SHA;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var test = GenerateHash(textBox1.Text);
            textBox2.Text = test;
        }

        private string GenerateHash(string plaintext)
        {            
            string sContainer = string.Empty;
            string sProvider = MS_DEF_PROV;

            IntPtr hProv = new IntPtr();
            IntPtr hKey = new IntPtr(0);
            IntPtr phHash = new IntPtr();

            try
            {
                bool res = Crypt32.CryptAcquireContext(out hProv, sContainer, sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET);
                if (!res)
                {
                    bool res1 = Crypt32.CryptAcquireContext(out hProv, sContainer, sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);
                    if (!res1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("CryptAcquireContext is false for second time so exiting the hash.");
                        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        Win32Exception test = new Win32Exception(error);
                        MessageBox.Show("Last Win32 error code: " + error);
                        MessageBox.Show("Last Win32 error msg: " + test.Message);
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("hProv handle value is: " + hProv.ToString());
                //Once we have received the context, next we create hash object                
                bool hashCreateResponse = Crypt32.CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA, hKey, 0, ref phHash);
                if (!hashCreateResponse)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CryptCreateHash is false so exiting with last win32 error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                //Hash the data
                byte[] pbData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext);
                bool hashDataResponse = Crypt32.CryptHashData(phHash, pbData, (uint)plaintext.Length, 0);
                if (!hashDataResponse)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CryptHashData is false so exiting.");
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                uint paramLen = 0;
                byte[] paramValue = new byte[0];

                bool getHashParamResponse = Crypt32.CryptGetHashParam(phHash, 0x0002, paramValue, ref paramLen, 0);

                if (234 == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
                {
                    paramValue = new byte[paramLen];
                    bool getHashParamResponse1 = Crypt32.CryptGetHashParam(phHash, 0x0002, paramValue, ref paramLen, 0);
                }

                //destroy the key
                Crypt32.CryptDestroyKey(hKey);

                //Destroy the hash object
                Crypt32.CryptDestroyHash(phHash);

                //Release provider handle
                Crypt32.CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach(var item in paramValue)
                {
                    sb.Append(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(item));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }


    public class Crypt32
    {
        public enum HashParameters
        {
            HP_ALGID = 0x0001,   // Hash algorithm
            HP_HASHVAL = 0x2, // Hash value
            HP_HASHSIZE = 0x0004 // Hash value size
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(
out IntPtr phProv,
string pszContainer,
string pszProvider,
uint dwProvType,
uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptCreateHash(IntPtr hProv, uint algId, IntPtr hKey, uint dwFlags, ref IntPtr phHash);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptDestroyHash(IntPtr hHash);        

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptDestroyKey(IntPtr phKey);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptHashData(IntPtr hHash, byte[] pbData, uint dataLen, uint flags);

        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CryptReleaseContext", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptReleaseContext(IntPtr hProv,Int32 dwFlags);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptGetHashParam(IntPtr hHash,
        uint dwParam,
        Byte[] pbData,
        ref uint pdwDataLen,
        uint dwFlags);
        //public static extern bool CryptGetHashParam(IntPtr hHash, uint dwParam, [Out] byte[] pbData, [In, Out] uint pdwDataLen, uint dwFlags);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Platform Invoke Services (PInvoke) to call advapi32.dll functions from .NET.  This might speed up the migration process.

You can find signatures on http://pinvoke.net

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I have a working code now but the problem is that, the CryptAcquireContext is true only for the first time when I run the program. Subsequent calls to the program returns false at CryptAcquireContext. Can you please point me as to where I may be doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the error code that is returned by GetLastError when CryptAcquireContext returns false?

Comment: Actually I fixed the error by changing the last parameter of CryptAcquireContext function to 0. Seems like it is working fine now.

Comment: And Yes, earlier I tried to get the last error by using Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() function which returned 0. But as I mentioned in my earlier comment, changing the last parameter to 0 fixed it.

Comment: Joe, I deployed my small utility on one of the other server and it fails to get CryptAcquireContext. Can you think of any thing on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So finally with help of Joe's suggestion, PInvoke documentation and some code tweaks found on stack over flow, I was able to create a successful working windows form application that has 2 textboxes and a button. Enter plaintext in first textbox and click the button to get hash value in the second textbox. The complete code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CryptoGraphicHash
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static uint CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = 0x8;

        static uint CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET = 0x20;

        static uint ALG_CLASS_HASH = 32768;
        // Algorithm types
        static uint ALG_TYPE_ANY = 0;

        static uint PROV_RSA_FULL = 1;
        static uint ALG_SID_SHA = 4;

        static string MS_DEF_PROV = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
        static uint CALG_SHA = ALG_CLASS_HASH + ALG_TYPE_ANY + ALG_SID_SHA;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var test = GenerateHash(textBox1.Text);
            textBox2.Text = test;
        }

        private void HandleWin32Error()
        {
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(error);
            MessageBox.Show("Last Win32 error code: " + error);
            MessageBox.Show("Last Win32 error msg: " + ex.Message);
        }

        private string GenerateHash(string plaintext)
        {            
            string sContainer = string.Empty;
            string sProvider = MS_DEF_PROV;

            IntPtr hProv = new IntPtr();
            IntPtr hKey = new IntPtr(0);
            IntPtr phHash = new IntPtr();

            try
            {
                bool res = Crypt32.CryptAcquireContext(out hProv, sContainer, sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);
                if (!res)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CryptAcquireContext is false for first time so will try again with CRYPT_NEWKEYSET.");
                    HandleWin32Error();
                    bool res1 = Crypt32.CryptAcquireContext(out hProv, sContainer, sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET + CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);
                    if (!res1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("CryptAcquireContext is false for second time so exiting the hash.");
                        HandleWin32Error();
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("hProv handle value is: " + hProv.ToString());
                //Once we have received the context, next we create hash object                
                bool hashCreateResponse = Crypt32.CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_SHA, hKey, 0, ref phHash);
                if (!hashCreateResponse)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CryptCreateHash is false so exiting with last win32 error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                //Hash the data
                byte[] pbData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plaintext);
                bool hashDataResponse = Crypt32.CryptHashData(phHash, pbData, (uint)plaintext.Length, 0);
                if (!hashDataResponse)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CryptHashData is false so exiting.");
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                uint paramLen = 0;
                byte[] paramValue = new byte[0];

                bool getHashParamResponse = Crypt32.CryptGetHashParam(phHash, 0x0002, paramValue, ref paramLen, 0);

                if (234 == Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
                {
                    paramValue = new byte[paramLen];
                    bool getHashParamResponse1 = Crypt32.CryptGetHashParam(phHash, 0x0002, paramValue, ref paramLen, 0);
                }

                //destroy the key
                Crypt32.CryptDestroyKey(hKey);

                //Destroy the hash object
                Crypt32.CryptDestroyHash(phHash);

                //Release provider handle
                Crypt32.CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach(var item in paramValue)
                {
                    sb.Append(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(item));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }


    public class Crypt32
    {
        public enum HashParameters
        {
            HP_ALGID = 0x0001,   // Hash algorithm
            HP_HASHVAL = 0x2, // Hash value
            HP_HASHSIZE = 0x0004 // Hash value size
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(
out IntPtr phProv,
string pszContainer,
string pszProvider,
uint dwProvType,
uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptCreateHash(IntPtr hProv, uint algId, IntPtr hKey, uint dwFlags, ref IntPtr phHash);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptDestroyHash(IntPtr hHash);        

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptDestroyKey(IntPtr phKey);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptHashData(IntPtr hHash, byte[] pbData, uint dataLen, uint flags);

        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CryptReleaseContext", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptReleaseContext(IntPtr hProv,Int32 dwFlags);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CryptGetHashParam(IntPtr hHash,
        uint dwParam,
        Byte[] pbData,
        ref uint pdwDataLen,
        uint dwFlags);
        //public static extern bool CryptGetHashParam(IntPtr hHash, uint dwParam, [Out] byte[] pbData, [In, Out] uint pdwDataLen, uint dwFlags);
    }   
}
```